# Check if over 18 years, only works from 1960->1994

Tags: php, forms

I am having some troubles with my form. The PHP is going to check if the age is under 18, and if so, the person gets a message that he needs to be over 18. However, the form only works when the person is born between 1960-1994. If the person is born 1950, he gets a message that he is not 18 years...

What is wrong with my code?

```
if(empty($_POST["born"])) {$born_error = ('<span class="notutfyllt">*Fødselsår is not filled out</span><br/>');}
else {
        $today = date_create('today');
        $born = date_create("{$_POST['born']}");
        $age = date_diff($today, $born)->y;

        } if ($age >= 18) {
            $born_error = "";
        } else { 
            $born_error = ('<span class="notutfyllt">*You need to be 18 year</span><br/>');
        }
```

From the form:

```
<label for="born">Year of born:</label>
      <input type="text" name="born" id="born" value="'.$born.'">
```

New version:

```
if(empty($_POST["born"])) {$born_error = ('<span class="notutfyllt">*Fødselsår is not filled out</span><br/>');}
    else {
        $bday = new DateTime($_POST["born"]);
        $today = new DateTime('Y');
        $diff = $today->diff($bday);
        if($diff->y>18) {
            $born_error = "";
        }else {
            $born_error = ('<span class="notutfyllt">*You need to be 18 years</span><br/>');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST['born']`?

Comment: You can directly call `date_create($_POST["born"])`

Comment: Sounds like it may be taking any value below 60 as minutes...? What's the date format?

Comment: Try either switching `$today` and `$born` in your function call to `date_diff`, or pass `true` as the third argument to force the result to be positive.

Comment: For me `date_create("1950")` creates an object with the date of today, `date_create("1950-05-05")` creates an object with the correct date.

Comment: Thanks! I have no changed little bit of my code, but still get the same problem with born on 1950...

Answer (score 2):

Note from the [PHP manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php):

> The "Year (and just the year)" format only works if a time string has
>   already been found -- otherwise this format is recognised as HH MM.

Example:

```
$born = date_create('1950');
var_dump($born);
```

produces:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2013-12-05 19:50:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

I guess 1960 and above is an invalid time, so it is considered as a year. You will have to either ask for the complete birth date or add `"-01-01"` in your script (which will give wrong results for some people).

Comment: Thanks! How do I solve the problem? Do I need to define the input type as a date, and the user needs to post their YYYY MM DD birthday?

Comment: That would be the only correct solution. If you only ask for the year you would give someone who was born on 1995-12-20 access even if he is technically (today) still 17.

Answer (score 1):

Hence I can't comment I add this as a answer.

Your code is correct, but I guess something wrong in the input. That you should check how you give the input.

But I tested your code with 3,4 values, it works as below.

```
$born = date_create("1950-01-01");  //$age is 63
$born = date_create("1960-01-01");  //$age is 53
$born = date_create("1994-01-01");  //$age is 19
```

So you have check the input and input must be in a `format accepted by strtotime()`.

Finally I suggest to use a [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or something similar to that to restrict the user for entering wrong values.

Answer (score 1):

The new [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class will save you.

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', '1950'); // Pass your $_POST['born']
$cdate = new DateTime();
$age= $cdate->format('Y') - $date->format('Y');
if($age>18)
{
echo "You are above 18 years. You are allowed";
}
else
{
echo "Sorry you don't have access";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> You are above 18 years. You are allowed

Comment: Technically this would work, but as I wrote in my answer this would give wrong results for everybody who turns 18 between "now" and the end of the year.

Comment: Can you provide a test data (year) that contradicts the answer?

Comment: Thanks. But it works just the same way as the others. Still get the error when born in 1950... I guess the problem is in the form/input?

Comment: See i have put up an example with 1950 in the answer. How come it doesn't work for you ?

Comment: Sorry for no answer in a long time... But the code does not include $_POST['born']. How do I include that in your code?